# How to remove Windows 10 from Windows Boot Manager after uninstalling it?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-10

I installed Windows 7 on one partition and formatted the other where I had Windows 10 installed leaving only that one Windows 7 OS on my drive, but I still have two OSs offered in Windows Boot Manager. What is even weirder is that their names are reversed, when I choose Windows 10, it's Windows 7 that gets loaded.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To delete a version from the Windows Boot Manager screen:

1. Start the program `msconfig`
2. Go to the *Boot* tab
3. Select which Windows version you’d like to boot into directly
4. Press *Set as Default*
5. Delete the other version by selecting it and clicking *Delete*
6. Click *Apply*
7. Click *OK*
8. Restart the computer.

Comment: Wouldn't this still leave you with showing the Windows Boot Manager with only 1 entry, which would still be inaccurately labeled "Windows 10" as OP described?  Perhaps use bcdedit from cmd to correct the label?  Can the Boot Manager be hidden during boot from the msconfig dialog when there is only one entry?

Comment: @Blaelph: I believe that the menu wouldn't be displayed when there is only a single entry. In all cases, by reducing the Timeout value on the Boot tab one can reduce the time that the menu is displayed when a default entry is defined.

Comment: What if you can't boot into Windows?

Comment: @alex: You do that from whatever operating system you have, or UEFI software. But this is another question.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to @harrymc's answer, you can also use the Windows command line tool BCDEDIT to configure the Windows Boot Manager from an elevated command prompt.  The following instructions assume you are booted into Windows 7.

1. to open an elevated command prompt, press `Win`+`R` to open the `Run` dialog, then type:

   > cmd /admin
2. to list the Boot Manager settings, type:

   > bcdedit
3. To remove another entry, take note of the entry's `identifier` hex string (e.g. {00000000-0000-0000-000000000000}) and type:

   > bcdedit /delete {00000000-0000-0000-000000000000} /remove
4. To rename the `description` of the `{current}` entry to "Windows 7", type:

   > bcdedit /set {current} description "Windows 7"
5. If you wish to not display the Boot Manager on boot if you only have one entry, you can use this command:

   > bcdedit /set {bootmgr} displaybootmenu no

Answer (score 0):

Win 10: Try going to your BIOS and reset to defaults. It worked for my HP laptop after I migrated to SSD using macrium reflect 7.x.